# Picture Gallery won't align wright (html, css)

Tags: html, css

I am working on my school project and my Picture Gallery won't fit into the screen as intended.

After the third picture it just goes down instead of align in one row. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also the sizes are all different from the outline and I have no clue how to make them one size.

```css
div.gallery {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  float: left;
  width: 180px;
}

div.gallery:hover {
  border: 1px solid #777;
}

div.gallery img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto
}

div.description {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <a target="_blank" href="NationalMall.jpeg">
    <img src="NationalMall.jpeg" alt="NationalMall" width="600" height="400">
  </a>
  <div class="description"> National Mall in Washington DC </div>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a target="_blank" href="GrandCanyon.jpeg">
    <img src="GrandCanyon.jpeg" alt="GrandCanyon" width="600" height="400">
  </a>
  <div class="description"> GrandCanyon in Arizona </div>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a target="_blank" href="GettysBurg.jpeg">
    <img src="GettysBurg.jpeg" alt="Gettysburg" width="600" height="400">
  </a>
  <div class="description"> Gettysburg in Pennsylvania</div>

  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="NewYork.jpeg">
      <img src="NewYork.jpeg" alt="NewYork" width="600" height="400">
    </a>
    <div class="description"> NewYork City an der Ostküste </div>
  </div>

  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="Disneyworld.jpeg">
      <img src="Disneyworld.jpeg" alt="Disneyworld" width="600" height="400">
    </a>
    <div class="description"> Disneyworld in Orlando Florida </div>
  </div>

  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="LasVegas.jpeg">
      <img src="LasVegas.jpeg" alt="LasVegas" width="600" height="400">
    </a>
    <div class="description"> Las Vegas in Nevada </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You're missing a closing `</div>` on your third gallery item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some code issue in your HTML, you have not added it properly. here i have added HTML and CSS.

**CSS CODE**

```css
div.gallery {
    margin:5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
  
    width: 180px;
    
}
    div.gallery:hover {
    border: 1px solid #777;
}

    div.gallery img {
        width:100%;
        height:auto
    }

    div.description {
        padding: 15px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .gallery-items .gallery{
   float: left
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery-items">
      <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="NationalMall.jpeg">
          <img
            src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"
            alt="NationalMall"
            width="600"
            height="400"
          />
        </a>
        <div class="description">National Mall in Washington DC</div>
      </div>

      <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="GrandCanyon.jpeg">
          <img
            src="https://picsum.photos/200/300
"
            alt="GrandCanyon"
            width="600"
            height="400"
          />
        </a>
        <div class="description">GrandCanyon in Arizona</div>
      </div>

      <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="GettysBurg.jpeg">
          <img
            src="https://picsum.photos/200/300
"
            alt="Gettysburg"
            width="600"
            height="400"
          />
        </a>
        <div class="description">Gettysburg in Pennsylvania</div>
      </div>

       <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="GettysBurg.jpeg">
          <img
            src="https://picsum.photos/200/300
"
            alt="Gettysburg"
            width="600"
            height="400"
          />
        </a>
        <div class="description">Gettysburg in Pennsylvania</div>
      </div>

       <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="GettysBurg.jpeg">
          <img
            src="https://picsum.photos/200/300
"
            alt="Gettysburg"
            width="600"
            height="400"
          />
        </a>
        <div class="description">Gettysburg in Pennsylvania</div>
      </div>
     
    </div>
```

Comment: Still not working, what did you all change?

Comment: @DrDinkelberg If it's not working, then why did you mark this as the answer?

Answer (score -1):

Try using .gallery{} and .description{} instead of div.gallery{}

Comment: Why would changing this answer the question? `div.gallery` is perfectly acceptable CSS.